# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'named_struct()' due to data type mismatch:

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I ran the spark application where i joined two datsets and formed one dataset,and using an Encoder I converted `Dataset<Row>` into `Dataset<T`> format.

Encoder looks as follows:

```
Encoder<RuleParamsBean> encoder = Encoders.bean(RuleParamsBean.class);

Dataset<RuleParamsBean> ds = new Dataset<RuleParamsBean>(sparkSession, finalJoined.logicalPlan(), encoder);

Dataset<RuleParamsBean> validateDataset = ds.map(rulesParamBean -> validateTransaction(rulesParamBean),encoder);
validateDataset.show();
```

And after the map operation over the dataset i am getting the error as follows:

```
Dataset<RuleParamsBean> ds = new Dataset<RuleParamsBean>(sparkSession, finalJoined.logicalPlan(), encoder);
```

#### Error Log

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'named_struct()' due to data type mismatch: input to function named_struct requires at least one argument;;

Relation[TXN_DETAIL_ID#0,TXN_HEADER_ID#1,TXN_SOURCE_CD#2,TXN_REC_TYPE_CD#3,TXN_DTTM#4,EXT_TXN_NBR#5,CUST_REF_NBR#6,CIS_DIVISION#7,ACCT_ID#8,TXN_VOL#9,TXN_AMT#10,CURRENCY_CD#11,MANUAL_SW#12,USER_ID#13,HOW_TO_USE_TXN_FLG#14,MESSAGE_CAT_NBR#15,MESSAGE_NBR#16,UDF_CHAR_1#17,UDF_CHAR_2#18,UDF_CHAR_3#19,UDF_CHAR_4#20,UDF_CHAR_5#21,UDF_CHAR_6#22,UDF_CHAR_7#23,... 102 more fields] JDBCRelation(CI_TXN_DETAIL_STG_DUMMY) [numPartitions=1]

Relation[ACCT_ID#377,ACCT_NBR_TYPE_CD#378,ACCT_NBR#379,VERSION#380,PRIM_SW#381] JDBCRelation(CI_ACCT_NBR_DUMMY) [numPartitions=1]

at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:93)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:95)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:95)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpression$1(QueryPlan.scala:106)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:120)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:125)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.mapExpressions(QueryPlan.scala:125)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsUp(QueryPlan.scala:95)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:91)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:172)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:178)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedPlan(Dataset.scala:3300)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.map(Dataset.scala:2569)
at com.sample.Transformation.main(Transformation.java:100)
```

Comment: I have the same issue. The issue started occurring when I've switched from Spark 2.2.1 to Spark 2.3.0, but I haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: In my case the problem was that the JavaBean that I was using in the Dataset had a field of type Object that sometimes was null. I've removed that variable and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was because of unsupported type. I was using LocalDate which was not supported in Spark 2.X I guess.(I think they included support for it in version 3)

I simply changed it from LocalDate to TimeStamp and it worked. Look if this is the case for you as well? Any type which is in your POJO which is not supported?